# How to update a regular C++ project to a CUDA runtime project in VS?

Tags: cuda, visual-studio-2019

How can I update a regular VC++ project into a CUDA runtime project in Visual Studio 2019?

I tried to add the CUDA markups of the vcxproj project file, without success.

I'm expecting to see the CUDA/C++ tree in project properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `<Project DefaultTargets="Build"` there should be:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CUDAPropsPath Condition="'$(CUDAPropsPath)'==''">
     $(VCTargetsPath)\BuildCustomizations</CUDAPropsPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

it defines the variable `CUDAPropsPath` used further.
In the same `<Project` :

```
 <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
   <Import Project="$(CUDAPropsPath)\CUDA 10.1.props" />
 </ImportGroup>
```

add the default parameters of CUDA/C++ and CUDA/linker in project properties.

For all the .cu files, we need in `<ItemGroup>` with the other cpp files:

```
<CudaCompile Include="MyKernel0.cu"/>
```

And in `<ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">` there must be:

```
<Import Project="$(CUDAPropsPath)\CUDA 10.1.targets" />
```

that adds the CUDA/C++ and CUDA/linker in project properties.